# Hard time creating arrays with For/Do

Tags: matrix, export, excel

So far this code Prints just a sequence of numbers, as you can see in the "Print"-Line.

I would like to export the results in one excel sheet, which has rows "b,l,m,d,p,best n, value" and in each column i have one result line.
How can I do that?

I think I have to first write a **list** instead of **Print**, which I append to each other to create a **table**. Then I export that table. Unfortuantely I am not able to create the lists, tables and export them even after reading the documentation.

```
B[n_, b_, l_, m_, d_, p_] := l+m-d-p+n
        For[b = 1, b < 3, b++;
         For[l = 5, l < 7, l++;
          For[m = 3, m < 5, m++;
           For[d = 3, d < 5, d++;
            For[p = 2, p < 3, p++;
             If[NMaxValue[{B[n, b, l, m, d, p], n >= 1}, 
                n \[Element] Integers] <= 0, Print[b, l, m, d, p, 0, 0] ,   (**)

              Print[b, l, m, d, p, 
               NArgMax[{B[n, b, l, m, d, p], n >= 1}, n \[Element] Integers], 
               NMaxValue[{B[n, b, l, m, d, p], n \[Element] Integers, n >= 1},
                 n]]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Thx all. Got it. How can i mark as solved?

Comment: You can click on the check mark of the answer of Gustavo in order to accept his answer.

Comment: did you actually want the numbers run together as your `Print` does?

Answer (score 6):

You are clearly a beginner. Experienced Mathematica users run away in panic when presented so many `For` loops. Using `Do` is better than nesting `For` and `Table` is better. In general you never `Print` something you want to export.

These steps may help you:

```
Table[
    If[
        NMaxValue[{B[n, b, l, m, d, p], n >= 1}, n ∈ Integers] <= 0
     ,  ToString /@ {b, l, m, d, p, 0, 0}
     ,  ToString /@ {b, l, m, d, p
          , NArgMax[{B[n, b, l, m, d, p], n >= 1}, n ∈ Integers]
          , NMaxValue[{B[n, b, l, m, d, p], n ∈ Integers, n >= 1}, n]
        }
     ]
   , {b, 2, 3}, {l, 6, 7}, {m, 4, 5}, {d, 4, 5}, {p, 3, 3}
]
```

> ```
> {{{{{{2,6,4,4,3,9,12.}},{{2,6,4,5,3,9,11.}}},{{{2,6,5,4,3,9,13.}},{{2,6,5,5,3,9,12.}}}},{{{{2,7,4,4,3,9,13.}},{{2,7,4,5,3,9,12.}}},{{{2,7,5,4,3,9,14.}},{{2,7,5,5,3,9,13.}}}}},{{{{{3,6,4,4,3,9,12.}},{{3,6,4,5,3,9,11.}}},{{{3,6,5,4,3,9,13.}},{{3,6,5,5,3,9,12.}}}},{{{{3,7,4,4,3,9,13.}},{{3,7,4,5,3,9,12.}}},{{{3,7,5,4,3,9,14.}},{{3,7,5,5,3,9,13.}}}}}}
> ```

```
Flatten[%, 4]
```

> ```
> {{2,6,4,4,3,9,12.},{2,6,4,5,3,9,11.},{2,6,5,4,3,9,13.},{2,6,5,5,3,9,12.},{2,7,4,4,3,9,13.},{2,7,4,5,3,9,12.},{2,7,5,4,3,9,14.},{2,7,5,5,3,9,13.},{3,6,4,4,3,9,12.},{3,6,4,5,3,9,11.},{3,6,5,4,3,9,13.},{3,6,5,5,3,9,12.},{3,7,4,4,3,9,13.},{3,7,4,5,3,9,12.},{3,7,5,4,3,9,14.},{3,7,5,5,3,9,13.}}
> ```

```
toExcel = StringJoin /@ %
```

> ```
> { "26443912.", "26453911.", "26543913.", "26553912.","27443913.","27453912.", "27543914.","27553913.","36443912.", "36453911.","36543913.","36553912.", "37443913.","37453912.","37543914.","37553913."}
> ```

```
Export["file.xls", toExcel]
```

Answer (score 2):

another approach:

```
B[n_, b_, l_, m_, d_, p_] := l + m - d - p + n
{##, If[(amax = 
       NArgMax[{B[n, Sequence@##], n >= 1}, Element[n, Integers]]) > 
     0, Sequence @@ {amax, B[amax, Sequence@##]}, 
    Sequence @@ {0, 0}]} & @@@ 
          Tuples[{
             Range[2, 3], Range[6, 7], Range[4, 5],
             Range[4, 5], Range[3, 3]}]
Export["test.xlsx", %]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of Sequence in `Sequence@##` ?