# How I can go to a new line in a nested For-loop?

Tags: output-formatting, core-language

How I can go to a new line in the following code:

```
M = 2; 
L = 2; 
For[n = 1, n <= M, n++, For[k = 0, k <= L, k++, Print[u[n, k] = n*k]]]
```

I want to go to a new line after running the inner loop. Can I use `\n`?

I want to have:

[image: PIC]

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Karsten 7 I want to have new line, for this code I want to have `0    1    2` and the new line `0    2    4`.

Comment: What are your actual goals here?  The approach you've chosen in unlikely to match your goals.  
In a notebook, print adds a cell to the notebook.

Comment: probably better to make a `Table` and use `MatrixForm` or `TableForm`

Comment: `Scan[Print[# Range[0, 2]] &, {1, 2}]`

Comment: In Mathematica, is there any similar key `"\n"` of `c++`?

Comment: Please take a look how to transistion from loops to more idiomatic approach: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144547/5478

Comment: If you are really intent on "printing" individual items and somewhat controlling the format you can use `WriteString[$Output,expr]` with `"\n"` as needed for line breaks.  I'd really encourage you not to try to write `c` in mathematica though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding `For`, `ApendTo`<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70149/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127644/121)</sup>, and `GraphicsGrid`:

```
Grid[
  Array[Times, {2, 3}, {1, 0}],
  Spacings -> {4, 1}
]
```

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & \text{   } & 1 & \text{   } & 2 \\
 0 & \text{   } & 2 & \text{   } & 4 \\
\end{array}$

Answer (score 3):

Perversion of `"\n"` ([StringRiffle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html)):

```
StringRiffle[Table[i j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 0, 2}], "\n", "\t"]
```

[image]